# Laravel 5.7: Laravel Datatable is not installing with Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.7

Trying to Install [Laravel Datatable](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) with this command with Composer:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^8.0
```

But nothing is loading.

When I am updating composer then it is hanging with this info:

```
> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
> dependencies (including require-dev)
```

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.20",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried updating composer itself? `composer self-update`

Comment: @TravisBritz no

Comment: @Pagol well how old is your version of composer (`composer --version`)? If it's not the latest stable (1.7.2), run `composer self-update` and then try requiring your package again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last it has worked.

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

After running this command I have run this below command

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
```

then installed the package within 2 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

First check if there is a `composer.lock` file is there, if it is, then it will bind you to those specific packages. If you want to install it, then remove composer.lock and then re-try the process and it will download the package.

Make sure to share the composer.lock among your peers via git or something similar, so that all are using the same package and same version.

Comment: @Pagol What do you mean by hanging?

Comment: Not loading or downloading any file.

Comment: @Pagol Downvoting a helpful answer will not help. Share the issue, what's the message you are getting?

Comment: I didn't give any Downvote....I have added what I am getting answer....